# influxdata telegraf with apache proxy issue

Tags: debian, apache2, reverse-proxy, telegraf

I have been using influxdata telegraf metrics collector for some time on windows and had no issues using the URL for influxdb to be a host that has apache with a  setup reverse proxy that forwards to actual influxdb host.
I just started using telegraf on linux v 1.2.1 on debian and experienced a weird issue.

All requests that telegraf would sent with the URL for influxdb to the host with apache revers proxy will fail as they are executed on the apache host instead of forwarded to the actual infxluddb host

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this behavior?

I tried apache reveres proxy with actual   and also a separate vhost on separate custom port that forwards when

Neither ways worked